# Bootmgr Menu set to display but does not run

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootmgr

I have two boot items in bootmgr.  It is set to display with 30 second timeout.

From a cold reboot the menu does not display and the last config (Win 10 with HyperV on) is loaded.

Is there another option I am missing?

This is the output of bcdedit

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {a56fe521-f848-11ea-a990-9cb70debdded}
displayorder            {current}
                        {default}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30
displaybootmenu         Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {39029d55-1d28-11ea-b604-d067e54ec74e}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {a56fe521-f848-11ea-a990-9cb70debdded}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Auto

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10 No Hyper-V
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {39029d55-1d28-11ea-b604-d067e54ec74e}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {a56fe521-f848-11ea-a990-9cb70debdded}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
hypervisorlaunchtype    Off
```